# What is the best way to extract unique URLs and related link text via perl mechanize?

Tags: perl, mechanize

I have created the following perl script to extract URLs from the web:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw( uniq );
use WWW::Mechanize  qw( );

my ($url) = @ARGV;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();


sub getUrl {
    my $request= "@_";
    my $response = $mech->get($request);
    return $response->is_success()  or die($response->status_line() . "\n");
}

sub getLinks {
    getUrl($url);
    my @root= map { "$_\n" } sort { $a cmp $b } uniq 
        map { $_->url_abs() }
            $mech->links();
    return @root;
}
print Dumper(getLinks());
```

Is there a solution how to extract unique URLs and related link text from a HTML site?

Comment: Why do you suppress the line number of the `die` statement by appending a newline?

Comment: The line number option created only for debugging.

Comment: ...and you are finished debugging...?

Comment: You don't need to use `&` to call Perl's sub: `getUrl($url)` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [HTML::LinkExtor](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.71/lib/HTML/LinkExtor.pm) - Extract links from an HTML document

See the [Example](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.71/lib/HTML/LinkExtor.pm#EXAMPLE) in the module, will help you lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $urls;
my @result;

foreach my $link ( $mech->links() ) {
    next if exists $urls->{ $link->url_abs() };
    push @result, {
        url => $link->url_abs(),
        text => $link->text(),
    };
    $urls->{ $link->url_abs() } = 1;
}
#now you have all unique links in the array of hashes @result
#so you can sort this array like you want...
```